# custom Django admin action returning invalid literal error

Tags: python, django

I have a django model `Customer` and I built a custom admin action to update one of the model fields. To create the action I created functions as follows:

```
def age(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
if customer.Age == '60 +':
    customer.Age = 0
elif customer.Age == '36 - 59':
    customer.Age = 1
else:
    customer.Age = 2
return customer.Age

def education(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    if customer.Education == 'Highschool and below':
        customer.Education = 0
    else:
        customer.Education = 1
    return customer.Education

def employment(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    if customer.Employment == 'Student':
        customer.Employment = 0
    elif customer.Employment == 'Contract':
        customer.Employment = 1
    else:
        customer.Employment = 2
    return customer.Employment

def stability(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    if customer.Employer_Stability == 'Unstable':
        customer.Employer_Stability = 0
    else:
        customer.Employer_Stability = 1
    return customer.Employer_Stability

def residential(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    if customer.Residential_Status == 'Rented':
        customer.Residential_Status = 0
    else:
        customer.Residential_Status = 1
    return customer.Residential_Status

def salary(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    if customer.Salary <= 1000:
        customer.Salary = 0
    elif 1000 < customer.Salary <= 10001:
        customer.Salary = 1
    else:
        customer.Salary = 2
    return customer.Salary

def loyalty(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    if customer.Customer_Loyalty <= 2:
        customer.Customer_Loyalty = 0
    else:
        customer.Customer_Loyalty = 1
    return customer.Customer_Loyalty

def balance(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    if customer.Balance <= 2500:
        customer.Balance = 0
    elif 2500 < customer.Balance <= 10001:
        customer.Balance = 1
    else:
        customer.Balance = 2
    return customer.Balance

def feat_list(age, education, employment, stability, residential, salary, 
        loyalty, balance):
    total = age() + education() + employment() + stability() + residential() 
        + salary() + loyalty() + balance()
    return total

def allocate_service(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    platinum_customers = []
    silver_customers = []
    gold_customers = []
    message = ''

    for customer in queryset:
        if feat_list() <= 11:
            customer.Service_Level = Service.objects.get(service_name = 
                'Silver Package')
            silver_customers.append(customer.Name)
        elif feat_list() > 11 and feat_list() <= 15:

            customer.Service_Level = Service.objects.get(service_name = 
               'Gold Package')
            gold_customers.append(customer.Name)
        else:
             customer.Service_Level = Service.objects.get(service_name = 
                'Platinum Package')
            platinum_customers.append(customer.Name)
        customer.save()

        if platinum_customers:
            message = 'The following customers are now Platinum Customers: 
                {}'.format(', '.join(platinum_customers))
        if silver_customers:
            message = 'The following customers are now Silver Customers: 
                {}'.format(', '.join(silver_customers))
        if gold_customers:
            message = 'The following customers are now Gold Customers: 
                {}'.format(', '.join(gold_customers))
        if not platinum_customers and not silver_customers and not 
            gold_customers:
            message = 'No customer changes made!'
        ModelAdmin.message_user(request, message, level=SUCCESS)
allocate_service.short_description = 'Allocate Service'
```

The CustomerAdmin is as follows:

```
@admin.register(models.Customer)
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    icon = '<i class="material-icons">account_box</i>'
    list_display = ('Customer_ID', 'Name', 'Gender', 'Nationality', 
        'Account_Type', 'Salary', 'Balance', 'Service_Level')
    list_per_page = 20
    list_filter = ('Nationality', 'Gender')
    actions = [allocate_service]
```

The problem here is that when I try to run the Action I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4941" class="action-select'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing integers with strings and overwriting model values.

```
elif customer.Age == '36 - 59':
    customer.Age = 1
```

Your model can't represent a string `'36 - 59'` and an integer `1`.

Instead you should be tracking these values as their own variables, for example:

```
def education(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    education = 0
    if customer.Education == 'Highschool and below':
        education = 0
    else:
        education = 1
    return education
```

This can be shortened to

```
def education(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    if customer.Education == 'Highschool and below':
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

Finally, if you have the ability to change the database schema, you may want to consider using [`choice fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices) instead of strings to store these values.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. I have updated my code to your recommendation but I am still getting the error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '21" class="action-select'`